# SDK problem after GitHub import to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, sdk

I am new to programming.
I have never coded and I have never used Android Studio and GitHub.
Sorry if I ask stupid questions.
I downloaded this project in ZIP on GitHub: https://github.com/raghavtilak/Paint

When I open it in Android Studio, I get an error message:
"The SDK path 'C:\Sdk\Sdk' does not belong to a directory.
Android Studio will use this Android SDK instead : 'C:\Users\jane\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' and will modify the projectct's local."

What should I do to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the project in Android Studio it should ask you to change the SDK path automatically. If it does you can just accept it and it will change the path without you noticing and without any problems.

If it does not ask you, just search your SDK Path (on your computer) and change it in your `local.properties` in the project panel (or the windows explorer) in android studio.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Then please mark this answer as accepted...